# Why isn't this code able to centre the text on the graphics object?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I've been hit and miss with using the graphics object method `MeasureCharacterRanges()`.  Below is example code where it doesn't work.  When the rectangle is drawn, it's not around the 'X', but *slightly to the left*.

'X', clearly, does not mark the spot.

Why?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string test = "X";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
        {
            g.Clear(this.BackColor);
            using (Font font = new Font(Font.Name, this.Size.Height / 8))
            {
                Rectangle layout = this.ClientRectangle;
                layout.Width *= 2;

                using (StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat())
                {
                    CharacterRange[] charRange = { new CharacterRange(0, test.Length) };
                    stringFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(charRange);
                    Region[] sr = g.MeasureCharacterRanges(test, font, layout, stringFormat);

                    RectangleF rectangle = sr[0].GetBounds(g);

                    PointF location = new PointF((this.ClientRectangle.Width - rectangle.Width) / 2.0f, ((this.ClientRectangle.Height - rectangle.Height) / 2.0F));
                    rectangle.Location = location;
                    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
                    {
                        g.DrawString(test, font, brush, rectangle.Location);
                    }
                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Rectangle.Round(rectangle));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the evil `CreateGraphics` when the event args you receive already owns a `Graphics` object?

Comment: Because this is an example I created from code that doesn't run as the result of a Paint event.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Outside this context, why do consider `CreateGraphics` evil?

Comment: It's expensive and volatile.  Since this code isn't in a `Paint` event, anything that causes change or refresh to the DC can destroy what you've drawn.  Best to get it in a `Paint` event where you have reliable access to keep it drawn correctly.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I refactored all my code to avoid using it.  Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your StringFormat with the [GenericTypographic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat.generictypographic%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, and then pass the stringFormat into the DrawString method with one of the other overloads so that it knows about the StringFormat you've specified.

If you don't do this, DrawString just uses the default StringFormat which doesn't have the correct Property values for Trimming, FormatFlags and Alignment etc.

```
    // StringFormat created using GenericTypographic
    using (StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic))
    {
        CharacterRange[] charRange = { new CharacterRange(0, test.Length) };
        stringFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(charRange);
        Region[] sr = g.MeasureCharacterRanges(test, font, layout, stringFormat);

        RectangleF rectangle = sr[0].GetBounds(g);

        PointF location = new PointF((this.ClientRectangle.Width - rectangle.Width) / 2.0f, ((this.ClientRectangle.Height - rectangle.Height) / 2.0F));
        rectangle.Location = location;

        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
        {
            // Now passing in stringFormat
            g.DrawString(test, font, brush, rectangle.Location, stringFormat);
        }
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Rectangle.Round(rectangle));

    }
```